# Youtube videos are not streaming in <video> of HTML5

Tags: html, video, youtube, h.264

I'm trying to stream youtube videos with  tag, the videos uploaded were .mp4 and supports h.246 codecs.

Code snippet as below,

```
<html>    
<body>    
<video control autoplay>    
<source src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?=RB_hVB6qzBc" type="video/mp4" codecs="h.264"></source>    
</video>    
</body>    
</html>
```

This page is not displaying any video neither in Chrome - WINDOWS XP or in Chrome on Android 2.3.

The  tag is working fine when we point the source to an video url of amazon cloud.

We are facing this problem only when same video accessed via Youtube.

Do source of  mandates extension like .mp4 etc to play a media file ? Because other than this accessing a video from amazon and accessing it over Youtube are just the same.

Help of this is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: YouTube doesn't work that way.  If you want to embed a video, use the embed links from the video page.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot use YouTube like that, it doesn't work that way.

First off, the link should be `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RB_hVB6qzBc` (note the `?v=`).  Second, that's a link to the video page, not the MP4 file itself.

If you want to embed a YouTube video, use the embed code they provide ("Share" > "Embed"):

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/RB_hVB6qzBc" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

If you *really* wanted to use your own `<video>` tag to play the file, you'd have to get the actual video URL.  You'd have to get the `<video>` tag from the YouTube page, and get the URL, and then use that.  But, I'm pretty sure YouTube doesn't want you doing that.

Comment: that's just a typo. I'm using the url from Youtube    http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RB_hVB6qzBc; you mean to say there is no way we can play videos from Youtube with video tag in HTML5 ? :-(

Comment: @user1252573: `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RB_hVB6qzBc` is just a link to the video page, not the MP4 file.  You *can* play YouTube videos using your own `<video>` tags, but I don't know if YouTube wants you doing it.  I suggest using the embed link they provide.

Comment: @user1252573: http://o-o.preferred.sjc07s11.v21.lscache6.c.youtube.com/videoplayback?sparams=cp%2Cid%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Cratebypass%2Csource%2Cexpire&fexp=908920%2C916104%2C906024%2C910017&itag=18&ip=50.0.0.0&signature=14D4A46D2822BEBCD67323D49D9E4832F5C85AAE.B2243BA977258F725886EA26868577402611E021&sver=3&ratebypass=yes&source=youtube&expire=1331077292&key=yt1&ipbits=8&cp=U0hSRlBSVV9OTENOMl9ITFlDOlRsUURoemVnOXk4&id=441fe1541eaacc17 This is the URL, YouTube uses for its HTML5 player.  It may or may not work, and like I said, I don't know if they want you using it.

Comment: Prior to posting this question, I tried with that URL, it is displaying a video with no-sync between audio and video and top of it it kind freezing in between, I have a fairly good bandwidth here.

Comment: @user1252573: I don't know what to tell you.